# How to capture a screenshot of specific element or position using Capybara Webkit?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webkit, capybara, capybara-webkit

Is possible to capture a screenshot of a specific element or portion of the rendered page using [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/)?

This can be easily accomplished with Capybara + Poltergeist (phantomjs driver), since it offer a non standard save_screenshot(path, selector) method.

[Looking at capybara-webkit documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Session#save_screenshot-instance_method) we can see the `options` parameter for the `#save_screenshot`. But digging deeper, I found only `width` and `height` examples.

I need for instance, capture a screenshot displaying only a rendered `img` element during Capybara session. And that image is available at the bottom of the page.

This is possible using [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/)? How?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Mission accomplished.

For those interested, I solved the issue using the imagemagick CLI:

```
session.save_screenshot(temp_file_path)
system("convert #{temp_file_path} -crop <width>x<height>+<left>+<top> +repage #{temp_file_path}")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I skipped over the part where it says "*of a specific element or portion of the rendered page*", so the answer below is for screenshots in general.

---

You can save the current HTML by calling `save_and_open_page`.
Depending on what you want to accomplish, this might be way better than a screenshot or of no use at all...

On drivers that support it, there's also `page.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')`

For more details see the [README on Debugging](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#debugging)